# About linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Find:

a) $T:l^{2}\rightarrow l^{2}$ linear and discontinuous.

b) $T: l^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ linear and discontinuous.

Where $l^{2}$ is a $l^{p}$ space.

Anyone have a canonical example? If anyone can help me I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler example, consider the space $X = \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{R} e_i$. The linear map $X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $e_n \to n$ is not continuous; it isn't bounded. Similarly, the map $X \to X$ defined by $e_n \to n e_n$ is not continuous. The case of $\ell^2$ follows similarly; take a Hamel basis of it.